# Responsive website layout-columns

Tags: html, css, layout

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKiKy.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMHvI.png)

In the first image, the right column is as it should be, but at 767px(second image) I want it to go under the left column and be 100% wide. But, it spans all the way from the top and not from the "Tech skills" heading.
How do I fix this?

```
.left-column,
.right-column{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.left-column,
.right-column{
    width: 49.2%;
}
.left-column{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.row {
    zoom: 1; 
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){

.left-column,
.right-column{
    width: 100%;
}

.right-column{
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to also reset the float on the left column.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .left-column,
  .right-column {
    float: none;
    width: auto; /* rather than 100% to avoid overflow */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing against `flex` , you may use `min-width` to set a break point and eventually order to set right on top:

```css
.left-column,
.right-column {
  margin: 1%;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 360.5px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row:before,
.row:after {} .row:after {}
/* demo purpose */

.left-column,
.right-column {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
  background: tomato;
}
.left-column {
  background:orange
    }
.row div {
  min-height: 75vh;
}
h1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>play me fullpage and resize window :)</h1>
  <div class="left-column">
    left column
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    right column
  </div>
</div>
```

reorder stacking:

```css
.left-column,
.right-column {
  margin: 1%;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 360.5px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:row-reverse
}
.row:before,
.row:after {} .row:after {}
/* demo purpose */

.left-column,
.right-column {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
  background: tomato;
}
.left-column {
  background:orange;
  order:1
    }
.row div {
  min-height: 75vh;
}
h1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h1>play me fullpage and resize window :)</h1>
  <div class="left-column">
    left column
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    right column
  </div>
</div>
```